# HTML Validator: Library or command line tool

Tags: open-source, html, validation

I want to detect errors in my HTML during development.

Example:

```
<tr><td>foo</td><a href="...">...</a></tr>
```

This should be detected.

Required Features:

- open source
- self-hosting: the library should not need a service like https://validator.w3.org/
- Unknown attributes should get detected (example "hrf" instead of "href").
- extensible: There should be a way to configure it, so that non-standard attributes (example like https://htmx.org/) are ignored.
- Command line interface or library which is usable via python.
- Should work for html5

Background: I did a refactoring in my code and no automated test complained. But there were bugs (see above  example). I would like to automate html checking to be sure this does not happen again.

BTW: It is enough to detect the error. No automatic fixing should be attempted.

Comment: I always get some good initial results with xmllint. For the w3 validator did you have a look at https://github.com/w3c/link-checker.git?

Comment: @albert thank you for this hint, but html5 is not XML. For example `<br>` is valid, I don't want to write `<br />` :-). And thank you for the link-checker, but in my case I just want to check html5 syntax.

Comment: HTML5 and XML have a "same base", with xmllint you can also specify a dtd (see files xhtml-lat1.ent  xhtml-special.ent  xhtml-symbol.ent  xhtml1-strict.dtd  xhtml1-transitional.dtd), o you could probably do some more checking.

Comment: XML is a standard markup language that defines other markup languages like HTML.

Comment: @convert html is no longer xml. For example `<br>` is fine. You don't need to write `<br />` any more. I am so happy that html is no longer xml.

Comment: Not really good news, reading html was easier when it was xml. See no such big problem to have to use <br /> instead of <br>.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python library [html5validator](https://github.com/svenkreiss/html5validator)

> html5validator is a command line tool that tests files for HTML5 validity. This was written with static site generators like Jekyll and Pelican in mind. Dynamic html content (for example from JS template engines) can be crawled (e.g. with localcrawl) and then validated.

MIT License

Answer (score 1):

`xmllint` has a `--html` command line option : `--html : use the HTML parser` .

On Linux , xmllint is part of the `libxml2-utils` package.

Comment: This seams to fail for some html5 features: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717447/parse-html5-with-xmllint-invalid-tag

Comment: I speculate that the guy who asked that question has sent it his HTML through a pipe, calling `tidy` before xmllint . I think tidying up large `<SVG>` elements  can indeed be problematic` but that's more a problem of `tidy`. -- What HTML5 features do you have in mind?Problems with some specific tags? SVG? css? javascript?

Comment: A problem is that xmllint complains about non-HTML tags, which are allowed in HTML 5. It still processes and outputs them, so this just an annoyance.